How to register generic Type service in DI multiple times depending on the type passed to the generic class?
this is my service configuration
        public static IServiceProvider Configure()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddScoped<IUserFeedback, UserFeedback>();
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IMyInterface<Class1>), typeof(Class1ConcreteType));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IMyInterface<Class2>), typeof(Class2ConcreteType));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IMyInterface<Class3>), typeof(Class3ConcreteType));
        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

now trying to get an instance but failed with null object return
            ServiceProvider.Current = ServiceConfiguration.Configure();
            var interceptor = ServiceProvider.Current.GetService<IMyInterface<Class1>>();

result : interceptor =null

Was not able to reproduce, please provide a [mre].
